# How do I get the position of the keyboard's current focus in Rust or JS?

Tags: javascript, windows, rust, tauri

[image]

I want to get the position of the cursor the red circle and it dosen't have to support cross-platform.

If it works on Windows, that'll be enough.

I googled and found Enigo (a Rust package). But I didn't find functions I want in the package.

Comment: What code are you using to create the textbox?

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? (Since that looks like a screenshot from Discord rather than something you've written yourself.) If it's a web app then in Javascript `document.activeElement` will give you the currently-focused element. That's probably not what you want since you mention Windows - but then I'm not sure why you mention JS...

Comment: I'm not only talking about the web apps, I want to get the keyboard's focus wherever it is. And why I mentioned JS is that I'm creating a Windows app with Tauri.